# Can't locate custom module in @INC

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a basic Perl script that runs code from a module. After switching to a new computer, I am no longer able to run this script. The directory tree is set up like so:

```
SatanicBot
  src
    SatanicBot
      Bot.pm
      Utils.pm
  run.pl <-- The script that uses the module
```

The use statements in run.pl are like so:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

use Bot::BasicBot;

use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use FindBin;
use lib abs_path("$FindBin::Bin/SatanicBot");
# Without this, I get an error that is essentially caused by it not being to find the module.
use SatanicBot::Bot;
```

When I run run.pl, I get the following error:

```
Can't locate SatanicBot/Bot.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SatanicBot::Bot module) (@INC contains: /Users/elifoster/Desktop/Dev/SatanicBot/src/SatanicBot /Users/elifoster/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level /Users/elifoster/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0 /Users/elifoster/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/5.22.0/darwin-2level /Users/elifoster/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/5.22.0 .) at src/run.pl line 12.
```

As you can see, it states that @INC contains the directory that the SatanicBot::Bot module is in, yet it cannot find it. I'm seriously stumped.

Comment: What is `$FindBin::Bin/SatanicBot`? Probably not the same as `$FindBin::Bin/src/SatanicBot`

Comment: That should link to the correct location, because run.pl is already in the src directory. The second one would imply that Bot.pm is in SatanicBot/src/src/SatanicBot. At least that's what it seems like it would do.

Comment: Tip: `lib` is the conventional name for the directory containing the modules, not `src`. (`bin` for scripts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@INC` contains:

```
/Users/elifoster/Desktop/Dev/SatanicBot/src/SatanicBot
```

but to find the `SatanicBot::Bot` package in the file `/Users/elifoster/Desktop/Dev/SatanicBot/src/SatanicBot/Bot.pm`, you want `@INC` to contain

```
/Users/elifoster/Desktop/Dev/SatanicBot/src
```

Comment: try to do a   'find / -name Bot.pm -print' on the original machine to get the location then look at copying that file, the installer or the group of related files into your path.

Comment: This worked, but I'm left wondering why. The module file is not in /src, it's in /src/SatanicBot, so why does it prefer /src?

Comment: To find `Foo::Bar::Baz`, perl searches `@INC` for a file named `Foo/Bar/Baz.pm`, not a file named `Baz.pm`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!